# how can I add text to a list in a .txt file? with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of domains in a `.txt` file. How can I add to each domain the word `http://` and `https://`?

My domain list:

```
www.deepl.com
www.youtube.com
```

I need to generate a new list or `.txt` file, adding :

```
http://www.deepl.com
https://www.deepl.com
http://www.youtube.com
https://www.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a context manager like so:

```
with open("domain_list.txt") as r, open("new_list.txt", "w") as f:
    for domain in r:
        f.write("http://" + domain)
        f.write("https://" + domain)
```

Where `domain_list.txt` contains:

```
www.deepl.com
www.youtube.com
```

And the output `new_list.txt` contains:

```
http://www.deepl.com
https://www.deepl.com
http://www.youtube.com
https://www.youtube.com
```

Comment: I think you could also do `for domain in r:` and even get rid of the `+ "\n"`'s since they would still be on each line

Comment: @thisismy-stackoverflow Thanks! That would require an extra line in `domain_list.txt`, so I added it.